# Unhandled exception with class array size

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am trying to implement a least recently used algorithm program. I am prompting the user for the frames size. 
If i prompt and enter anything under a 6 it works perfecly. If i enter in anyhing with a 6 and above it throws an exception when its reading the inputstream(file) and adding it to the class.

```
inputStream >> pid;
inputStream >> ref;
```

file has like 7-8 lines im only showing 2 here.

```
1 45
1 46
```

Here is part of my class and main()

```
class pagetable
{

public:
int pid;
int ref;
int faults;
pagetable();
};

 pagetable::pagetable(){

pid = 0;
ref = 0;
faults = 0;
}
```

main()

```
while(!done){
 pagetable* page = new pagetable[frames];
ifstream inputStream;
getFileName(inputStream);//asks for input filename until it is valid

cout << "\nEnter in the number of frames:";
cin >> frames;
for ( i = 0; i < frames; i++ ) { //initializing
     page[i].pid = 0;
     page[i].ref = 0;


}
faults = runsimLFU2(inputStream, page, frames );

  void getFileName(ifstream &inputStream) //asks for input file until it is valid
{
char filename[MAXFILE];
while (inputStream.is_open() == false)
{
    inputStream.clear();
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Input filename: ";
    cin >> filename;
    inputStream.open(filename);
}
}
```

So, now i call a function that runs the LRU algorithm.
Thats where i get the error when i am parsing the file to the class. i commented the line im getting the error on.

```
int runsimLFU2(ifstream &inputStream, pagetable* page, int frames ){

int i =0;
int j=0;
int pid =0;
int ref = 0;
int index = 0;
int count = 0;
int pagefaults = 0;
int lowest=0;

int counter = 1;

int * LRU;
LRU = new int[frames];


while(1){

  inputStream >> pid;        //Error if frame is 6 or more
  inputStream >> ref;
  if( inputStream.eof() ) break;
    while(count < frames)
   {

       index  = searchForEmptySlotsLRU(page, frames);
```

Where it throws an error VS brings up the xlocale file, and i commented what line

```
_CRTIMP2_PURE void __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL _Incref()
        {   // safely increment the reference count
        _BEGIN_LOCK(_LOCK_LOCALE)
            if (_Refs < (size_t)(-1))   //error
                ++_Refs;
        _END_LOCK()
        }
```

Could it be how i am initializing? I need them to be initialized to zero because later on i check for empty slots.

i really dont get it because at that point im not adding anything to the class.

Thank you.

EDIT: I commented out the initializing in the class and its not throwing an exception anymore.

Comment: Can you post the exception info? Are you sure you want this `pagetable* page = new pagetable[frames];` in a loop? I don't know what surrounds that `while` but I highly doubt the allocation belongs there.

Answer (score 0):

You're corrupting memory somehow.

This looks really fishy:

```
while(!done){
    pagetable* page = new pagetable[frames];
    ifstream inputStream;
    getFileName(inputStream);//asks for input filename until it is valid

    cout << "\nEnter in the number of frames:";
    cin >> frames;
    for ( i = 0; i < frames; i++ ) { //initializing
        page[i].pid = 0;
        page[i].ref = 0;    
    }
```

What's the value of frames the first time? Try moving it below the `cin`.

```
while(!done){
    ifstream inputStream;
    getFileName(inputStream);//asks for input filename until it is valid

    cout << "\nEnter in the number of frames:";
    cin >> frames;
    pagetable* page = new pagetable[frames];
    for ( i = 0; i < frames; i++ ) { //initializing
```